# Windows10 WSL and Docker-Compose hidden folders

Tags: docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am just trying to get WSL running. I installed everything like described at https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/ and https://www.sitepoint.com/wsl2/

Now, when typing "wsl" into the powershell, i get my ubuntu-shell. I already mounted a folder a network drive from Ubuntu (var/www/html), where I checked out my projects. Docker is NOT installed on WSL due to the fact, that I read an article, which says, it is not neccessary any more when using WSL2.

The problem I have is the visibility of the project folders. It seems, that the half of the folders is just not visible in my containers. I don't know why, the folders don't appear inside my containers.
Now I read another article, which says, the docker-compose file has to be stored at the windows-system to keep this running, just the project files should be placed on wsl.

For me, this seems a little bit confusing, because I do not want to split my git-repo into two parts:

- the windows part with docker-compose and
- the wsl part with all my remaining code

Does anybody know a common working routine? How do you work with docker-compose and wsl?
How do you organize your projects?

Comment: Do the invisible folders start with `.`?

Comment: No, @dan1st, it are normal folders. The project has 5 root folders: docker, current, public, frontend, database. When setting up the volumesin docker-compose (    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html), i can't see database and frontend. I have no clue why, but I think, it is caused by the different file-servers